# Is Santa Company available to non-backers?

Tags: santa-company

I unfortunately missed the [kickstarter](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/itoso-tag/santa-company/) for Santa Company. Since I found out about it, I have been following the updates of the production and they have released the digital version to backers recently.

Is there anywhere I can purchase the movie digitally despite not having backed the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Santa Company Twitter account (@santa_company), for a limited time (not sure why), it can be purchased from this website.

http://santa-company.jugemcart.com/

Comment: Would you please include the link of the tweet and the webpages which lead to that website?